# If $f $ is a continuous function then $\exists a$ such that..

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Suppose $ f $ is a continuous function on the interval $[x,y]$; prove $\exists $ $a\in [x,y]$ such that $ f(a)=1/(y-x) \int^y_x fdx $.

I can't come up with a neat proof.

Theorem:
Let $ f $ be a continuous function on the interval $[x,y]$. If $ f(x)<f(y) $ and if $ b $ is a number such that $ f(x)<b<f(y) $ then $\exists a\in (x,y)$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Just to be clear are you asking how to use the theorem (intermediate value theorem) to prove the first statement?

Comment: Hint: if $m$ is the minimum of $f$ over $[x,y]$ and $M$ is the maximum, then $m\le{1\over y-x}\int_x^yf(s)\,ds\le M$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (thanks to Tryss)

If $f$ is continuous on this interval, then its antiderivative is differentiable, and what you have written follows from Mean Value Theorem:
$$
\exists x<a<y  s.t. f(a) = \frac{F(y) -F(x)}{y-x}
$$

Comment: No need for $f$ differentiable, it's F that must be differentiable, and here, as $f$ is continous, $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x) = x$

Comment: You do not need for differentiability! continuity is enough!

Comment: Already fixed.Thanks.

Comment: thank you. how did you come up with this so fast?

Comment: It's just a definition of MVT for $F(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[x,y]$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus the function $F(s) = \int_{x}^{s}f(t)dt$ is differentiable with $F'(s) = f(s)$. Then applying the Mean Value Theorem to $F$, there exists $a \in [x, y]$ such that $\frac{1}{y-x}\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt = \frac{F(y) - F(x)}{y - x} = F'(a) = f(a)$.